# Procedurally generated UVs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting

I have a procedurally generated cube that has a hole(s) in it. The script will take a mesh (the white squares in image 1) and creates the shown holes based on the position of the squares (image 2) (in other words, the squares are pretty much randomly placed.) The problem I'm having is that the light on the mesh is completely messed up (image 3). Currently the Array of UVs for the mesh is an empty Vector2 array. I believe that the UV array the problem so then how can I get the list of UVs when the only information I can get on the mesh is the list of vertices and the list of triangles? Or if it's not a problem with the UVs, how can I fix this? 
(In Unity C#)

[image]

[image: Mesh of Cube]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the problem has to do with the normals try:

```
mesh.RecalculateNormals();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless lighting is baked into the texture, it is more likely a problem with normals. You need to be more specific, show your shader code or how you generate vertices etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "shader code" and to generate the vertices, it's just getting all the x values and y values of each corner of the white squares and then doing the combination of each x and y point then I get the triangles from there by going through each point and making the triangle off it.

Comment: UV's are used to render a texture 'skin' over a mesh but you don't even say if you are using one. All I see is black with some kind of specular highlights which coincide with some quad looking corners. I recommend you read up a bit more on whatever system you are using to draw the object. Next time you ask a question, you should post some code or at least mention what you are using to render the image.

Comment: Woops, My bad Im using Unity C# to create the mesh

Comment: Shader code refers to the program used by the GPU to process the input data (mesh here) and to actually *draw* it. Unity has built-in shaders, but users can program their own for custom "effects". You should probably read a bit about rendering and Unity's pipeline.